# Reading 32 bit hex data from file

Tags: c++, binary, hex

What is the best way to go about reading signed multi-byte words from a buffer of bytes?

Is there a standard way to do this that I am not aware of, or am I on the right track reading in 4 chars and raising them to their respecting power of 16 and summing them together?

```
int ReadBuffer(int BuffPosition, int SequenceLength){
    int val = 0;

    int limit = BuffPosition + SequenceLength;
    int place = 0;
for( BuffPosition; BuffPosition < limit; BuffPosition++ ){
    int current = Buff[BuffPosition];
    current *= pow(16, (2*place));
    val += current;
    place++;
}

return val;}
```

Comment: Do you care about endianness?

Comment: There is no such thing as '32-bit hex data'. Hex is a string representation of binary data. What's in the file is almost certainly binary.

Comment: @EJP Probably OP just wants to dump 32 bit words into a file and read them later. I agree the terminology is not correct.

Comment: You are correct, I apologize for my lacking vocabulary. What I am trying to do is write 32 bit integers to file and then later read them into a buffer. Then read and manipulate them from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read/write your file on the same machine (same endianness), you can use a 32 bit type like `int32_t` (`#include <cstdint>`) and read directly. Small example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    const std::size_t N = 256; // length of the buffer
    int32_t buf[N]; // our buffer
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) // fill the buffer
        buf[i] = i;    

    // write to file
    file.write((char*)buf, N * sizeof(int32_t));
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) // zero-in the buffer
        buf[i] = 0; // to convince we're not cheating

    // read from file
    file.seekg(0); // rewind to beginning 
    file.read((char*)buf, N * sizeof(int32_t));
    // display the buffer
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) // fill the buffer
        std::cout << buf[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now realize that I can take a char* buffer and cast it to a data type with the correct size.

```
char* 8BitBuffer[4000];
int* 32BitBuffer;
if(sizeof(int) == 4){
     32BitBuffer = (int*)8BitBuffer;
}

dostuffwith(32BitBuffer[index]);
```

I am trying to process a wav file, so In an attempt to maximize efficiency I was trying to avoid reading from the file 44100 times a second. Whether or not that is actually slower than reading from an array I am not actually sure.